# Implementing transpose in Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, transpose, laravel-collection

This is a macro that I want to use it in Laravel collection. I know what the transpose is and how it works. But I didn't get exactly how this piece of code is implementing transpose in Laravel collection.

Can you explain how the items that we will pass, would be transposed?

What `new static($items)` does here?

```
Collection::macro('transpose', function () {
    $items = array_map(function (...$items) {
        return $items;
    }, ...$this->values());

    return new static($items);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided should be placed in a Service Provider according to the Laravel Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#extending-collections. However, you could technically place them anywhere.

What exactly don't you understand about the piece of code? The `macro` function of the `Illuminate\Support\Collection` accepts a closure. In this case, it means `$items` is referring to the Collection that `transpose` is called on.

Then that Collection is mapped (using `array_map`) and the `$items` are passed as a spread operator function parameter. Perhaps you're familiar with the spread operator, but it spreads the values of an array (or other iterable) to separate variables.

In that same function, these separate variables are returned, and the `values()` are provided as a spread operator to run through the callback function. For more information about `array_map`, you can read the PHP Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php.

If anything is unclear, please let me know what part needs clarification.